# Why does using ng-repeat for my directive make a difference to my binding?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

If we take the code:

```
    <div data-ng-repeat="video in vm.videos">
        <p>{{video.title}}</p>
        <video-item content="video"></video-item>
    </div>
```

it appears to render my directive correctly (the video object is bound correctly and accessible from my directive).

However if I only want to display a single video (same object type, just a single object rather than a collection):

```
    <p>{{vm.currentVideo.title}}</p>
    <div data-video-item content="vm.currentVideo"></div>
```

Then why does the scope no longer have access to the binding?

Here is my directive:

```
import Models = ROD.Domain.Models;

export class VideoDirective implements ng.IDirective {
    public restrict: string = "A";
    public replace: boolean = true;
    public scope: any = {
        content: "="
    };

    constructor(
        private $compile: ng.ICompileService,
        private templateSelector: ROD.Features.Video.Templates.ITemplateSelector<Models.IVideo>) {
    }

    public link: any = ($scope: IVideoScope, element: JQuery) => {
        const video: Domain.Models.IVideo = $scope.content;
        const template: string = this.templateSelector.buildTemplate(video);

        element.html(template);
        this.$compile(element.contents())($scope);
    };
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Provide a demo that replicates problem

Answer (score 1):

This was because the link function was being called before my data had been bound. The link function gets called immediately after the template has loaded, therefore it was too soon. I got around this by using ng-if around the HTML block to check if the value was set.